Computing the 21st derivative of $f(x) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{5} \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ at $x=0$

Given a function, $f(x) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^5\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$

Compute the value of 21st derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$
The answer given is  $\frac{10}{21!}$.
I proceeded with taking logarithm both the sides and differentiating but that was getting way lengthy. I also tried breaking it into partial fractions but that took me nowhere, please help proceed from here.

You mean $\sum_{n=1}^5 \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$?

@RobertIsrael  Oh my bad not summation but continued product, actually i am quite new tp stackexhange, so dont know how to type out that, i would rreally appreciate if you could edit that out.

Here is a mathjax tutorial

Ah sorry, actually it has asked 21st derivative at x=0, thanks @JonathanZ

You would need to use the series expansion of $\dfrac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ to get the answer. For $|x|<1$, we have $f(x)=(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots)(x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots)(x^4+x^8+x^{12}+\cdots)(x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+\cdots)$ (I'm writing out each terms of the product in case you have doubt), then you look at the coefficient of $x^{21}$, which turns out to be $10$. If you like, this is the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4+5x_5=21$.

By the way, the answer should be $10\times 21!$, not $\dfrac{10}{21!}$.

The coefficient of $x^6$ in $$\begin{align}\frac{f(x)}{x^{15}}&=\frac1{\prod_{n=1}^5(1-x^n)}\\&=(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^6)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^6)(1+x^4)(1+x^5)+o(x^6)\\&=(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^6)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)+o(x^6)\\&=(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^6)(1+x^2+x^3+2x^4+2x^5+3x^6)+o(x^6)
\end{align}$$
is
$$\frac{f^{(21)}(0)}{21!}=1+1+1+2+2+3=10.$$
